# VBA Change the background color of a toggle button when the toggle button is clicked

Tags: excel, vba, activex

Trying to use ActiveX Control `Toggle Button` in excel.
Before clicking on the button it's color is as per expectation like below image.

[image: Start Image]

But when I click on the button it's color changes to unreadable like below image.

[image: Stop Image]

Tried to change the `Backcolor` property in `Click` event but it's not working. It showing the same way.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Could you share the code used to change from `Start` to `Stop`?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

In Sheet module

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call CMDColorOnOff
End Sub
```

In Standard module

```
Sub CMDColorOnOff()
    If Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton1.BackColor = vbRed Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton1.BackColor = vbGreen
    Else
        Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton1.BackColor = vbRed
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Similarly, for font change, `ForeColor`.. But looking at the button caption, Start and stop, it seems like the button starts and stops a procedure(?). If so, the above code should be incorporated in that procedure. Turn on design mode on the developer tab and double click the button. See which procedure is called in the click event and edit the CommandButton properties set in that procedure code... Do turn off the design mode later.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve your problem by coding in vba.

Sub cmd_Btn_color()
'(Enter the name of your command button in the line below)
CommandButton.BackColor=vbaBlue
Endsub